# I Cant log in with a password that has been hashed

Tags: php, hash, password-encryption

I have the following code to sign up and it hashes the password which i can see in the database is successfully hashed

```
function newUser() {

    $forename = $_POST['forename'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $securityq = $_POST['securityq'];
    $securitya = $_POST['securitya'];
    $password =  $_POST['password'];

    $hash = password_hash ($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT );

    $query = "INSERT INTO admin (forename,surname,email,securityq, securitya,password) VALUES ('$forename','$surname','$email','$securityq','$securitya','$hash')";



    $data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error());
    if($data)
        {

    }
}
```

and the following is code is for my sign in page:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];


function SignIn()
{
    session_start();
    if (!empty($_POST['email']))
    {
        $query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM admin where email = '$_POST[email]' AND password = '$_POST[pass]'");

        $row = mysql_fetch_array ($query);
        if(!empty($row['email']) AND !empty($row['password']))
        {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['password'];

            echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('Successful Login')
            window.location.href='adminhome.php';
            </SCRIPT>");
        }
        else
        {
            echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('Invalid Login Credentials')
            window.location.href='adminsignin.php';
            </SCRIPT>");
        } 

    }
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    SignIn();
}
```

But I can't sign in at all with the password.
I've fiddled around with the sign in code but cannot find what I need to change to fix this issue,
many thanks, in advance.

Comment: *"which i can see in the database is successfully hashed"* - and what is that column's type and length?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Make sure you're not outputting before header neither.

Comment: Oh lord, you again. Not coding much of this site for yourself are you.

Comment: i've left the issues until now, dont you worry about how much i've coded myself

Comment: Well actually, the amount **you** have coded **is** exactly what is worrying me, and probably should be worrying your employer

Comment: Did you ever get the PDF stuff working?

Comment: Yeah, think I was so stuck on thinking i'd get it working the way we tried, once I started a fresh new page and a different method it worked

Comment: so........ where are we here? Marc gave you an answer; you're not saying much about whether or not it's working or not, nor have you said what errors you may be getting or the 2nd part of a question I asked you earlier. I voted to close your question, so it's up to you now to figure out what is failing. This is a debugging question.

Comment: the varchar length is 60 and so is the hash length -

Comment: Ok, well you can find me at [***the salad bar***...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910009/i-cant-log-in-with-a-password-that-has-been-hashed#comment53648556_32910089). Good luck, I've been on this question long enough, so have the others. I think I speak for everyone here. *ciao!*

Answer (score 4):

You never hash the password provided by the login form, so you're doing

```
if (real password == hashed string)
```

which will never match. You need something more like

```
$hash = password_hash ($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT );
$sql = "SELECT ... WHERE hash='$hash'";
```

And of course, you have gaping wide open [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities, so your login form is utterly useless.

Comment: `WHERE hash=$hash";` that's a string ;-)

Comment: I'm only building an Intranet site so SQL injection attack isnt the biggest issue I'm faced with at the moment.

Comment: Most site hacks are perpetrated by **internal staff** or with the help of **internal staff** Intranet is not synonimous with _safe from hackers_

Comment: If I don't see a green tick next to this answer within 2 minutes, I'm headed to the bar... the "salad" bar that is and not the *"hic, oops pardon me!"* bar, nor "foo bar" ;-)

Comment: @Andrew Very true, but they do have the good of SO at heart

Comment: Always like a family! XD

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari Si, [just like....](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_in_the_Family).

Comment: Great; the olives have been cleared out. I guess I'll be *bar hopping* now. *ciao tutti!*

Comment: Actually this will not work because of the salt, which is different for every new hash.

Comment: @martinstoeckli: we'll leave that to OP to discover...

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to search for a hashed password with an SQL statement, because the hash is salted. Instead you can read the hash from the database, and afterwards check whether the hash matches the provided password:

```
SELECT password FROM admin where email = ?
```

With this hash from the database you can verify the password:

```
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($_POST[pass], $existingHashFromDb);
```